# Is there a way to keep item names displayed?

Tags: torchlight

I'm not a fan of constantly hitting alt to see what loot is left on the ground. Is there a way to keep item names permanently displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can toggle this feature on and off by clicking a button at the bottom of the UI.  The button looks like a magnifying glass.

[image: Magnifying Glass Button]

If you toggle it 'on', pressing alt will *hide* loot.  Handy!